# How to switch between addClass and removeClass in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't get how to removeClass after a class has been added to an OBJ. For example, I click on a list item to give it class "complete", but I need to know how to remove class "complete" when I click on it again. Hopefully you understand.

```
<body>
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    
    <div>
      <form autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="todo" required autofocus>
        <input type = "submit">
      </form>
      <button onclick="deleteAll()">Delete All</button>
    </div>
    <ol class="taskList">
    </ol>
  
    <script>
    function addTask(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var task = $("#todo").val();
        $(".taskList").append("<li>"+task+"<div class='deleteIcon'>x</div></li>");
        $("#todo").val("");
        $("li").click(complete);
        $(".deleteIcon").click(deleteItem);
    }
    $("form").submit(addTask);
    $(".taskList").sortable();
      
    function complete(){
        $(this).addClass("complete");
    }
    function deleteItem(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
    function deleteAll(){
        $('li').each(function(){
            $('li').remove();
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think what you need is the toggleClass method to add or remove a class if the element already has it or not

Comment: Use: `$(this).toggleClass('complete')`

Comment: @AksJacoves If I repace .addClass() with .toggleClass() in my complete() function, I can only toggle some li's. Why is it and how to fix?

Comment: Is the code you posted here complete?

Comment: The problem lies in the way you call the click `$("li").click(complete)` event and the way you create the 'li' element

Comment: `$('li')` will take all li elements, you don't need them all, you just need the one that was just created

Comment: I will add a response with the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will create the element li in a different way so that we can use it later, for that I created the variable li with this element and then change this line: `$('li').click(complete)` to `$(li).click(complete)`

```js
function addTask(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var task = $("#todo").val();
        let li = $("<li>"+task+"<div class='deleteIcon'>x</div></li>") // new element li
        $(".taskList").append(li);
        $("#todo").val("");
        li.click(complete); // call this li
        $(".deleteIcon").click(deleteItem);
    }
    $("form").submit(addTask);
    // $(".taskList").sortable();
      
    function complete(){
        $(this).toggleClass("complete");
    }
    function deleteItem(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
    function deleteAll(){
        $('li').each(function(){
            $('li').remove();
        });
    }
```

```css
.complete {
  background: #f00;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
    
    <div>
      <form autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="todo" required autofocus>
        <input type = "submit">
      </form>
      <button onclick="deleteAll()">Delete All</button>
    </div>
    <ol class="taskList">
    </ol>
```

I created an example to demonstrate that it is working correctly here by adding a style to complete. Create the items and take the test right here, you will see that the items will alternate your 'complete' class

Comment: if you have a variable you don't need to do a new query with `$(li).click(complete); // call this i`
just write `li.click(complete);`

Answer (score 0):

the method you should use is:

```
  $(this).toggleClass("complete");
```

instead of:

```
  $(this).addClass("complete");
```

toggleClass() toggles adding or removing the class, while addClass() just adds it.